# caption name is too long and makes the espace between citation and number look bad

Tags: captions

How do I fix the caption of Abbildung so that it is not separated from the number? and that in the first one, why is the text not exactly under the figure 4.4?

thanks.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, height=0.7\textwidth]{Figures/4.5.jpg}
\captionsetup{width=0.6\linewidth}

\caption[MHZ2-20D pneumatischer Parallelgreifer]{\begin{tabular}{c} MHZ2-20D pneumatischer Parallelgreifer  \ \cite{amazon} \end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}\hfill

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth, height=0.7\textwidth]{Figures/4.6.jpg}
\captionsetup{width=0.7\linewidth}

\caption[3D gedruckte Greiferbacken]{\begin{tabular}{c} 3D bedruckte Greiferbacken  \ \cite{N} \end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image: as seen here]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which caption packages are you using? In the future could you please post a small example of code that can be compiled starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}` so people do not need to guess, as it stands the solution depends on which `caption` package you are using which we do not know

Comment: You should remove the `\begin{tabular}{c}` and `\end{tabular}` inside the mandatory argument of `\caption`, because inside a `c`-column of a `tabular` linebreaks are not provided. Depending on the class and packages you are using, centering of multiple lines of captions can be achieved either with class features or packages like `caption`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully sure what you want to achieve, so let me know what you think of the following. Captions are centered below the image and the images are aligned at the first line of the caption.
[image: Result]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[format=plain]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox%
        [MHZ2-20D pneumatischer Parallelgreifer]%               short caption
        {MHZ2-20D pneumatischer Parallelgreifer \cite{amazon}}% long caption
        [0.5\linewidth]%                                        width
        [c]%                                                    position of caption
        {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}%    content
    \subcaptionbox%
        [3D gedruckte Greiferbacken]%
        {3D bedruckte Greiferbacken \cite{N}}%
        [0.5\linewidth]%
        [c]%
        {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```